# Minicom serial echo on script execution

Tags: linux, minicom

I am trying to send a multi character command to a device controlled via serial using minicom but I do not fully understand the behaviour of the minicom-serial interaction I am seeing.

I have set the port to the desired baud rate (115200) and flow control settings.

Below my minirc settings file, minirc.SSI_SERIAL .

```
# Machine-generated file - use "minicom -s" to change parameters.
pu port             /dev/ttyS0
pu baudrate         115200
pu bits             8
pu parity           N
pu stopbits         1
pu rtscts           No
```

I then try to send a command via script with command

```
minicom SSI_SERIAL -S minis_command1
```

content of the **minis_command1** script:

```
sleep 1
send ***
```

that results in the expected device behaviour, however the minicom terminal only echoes back to me:

```
#*
```

where I would expect

```
#***
```

Then I try to run the following script

```
sleep 1
send load -r -b 0x80000 -m ymodem
```

but the device does not behave as expected and I get echoed back:

```
#l
#o
#a
#d
#
#-
#r
#
#-
#b
#
#0
#x
#8
#0
#0
#0
#0
#
#-
#m
#
#y
#m
#o
#d
#e
#m
#
#
```

I would expect

```
#load -r -b 0x80000 -m ymodem
```